# Find Area of trapezium with circle inside

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There is
 [a link to the question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880811/find-area-of-trapezium-with-circle-inside)

As well description:

We have a trapezium $ABCD$ and a circle inside it. all $4$ sides of trapezium are touching the circle. left side AB have length of $26\ cm$, and right side is $22 \ cm$. radius of a circle is $10\ cm$. With that knowledge we have to find the area of trapezium $ABCD$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The area is $20\left(\frac{AD+BC}{2}\right)$. So all we need to know is $AD+BC$.

Claim: This is equal to $AB+CD$. To show that $AD+BC=AB+CD$, use repeatedly the fact that if the line segments $PX$ and $PY$ are tangent to a circle, where $X$ and $Y$ are the points of tangency, then $PX=PY$.

Comment: Is not $area=10(AD+BC)$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati: Thanks, I thought it was diameter.